# When i am trying to export excel file in php 7 same code is working in php5

Tags: php, excel, excel-import

When i am trying to export excel file in php 7 same code is working in php5

`$worksheet =& new writeexcel_worksheet($name, $index, $this->_activesheet,
                                  $this->_firstsheet,
                                  $this->_url_format, $this->_parser,
                                  $this->_tempdir);`

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'new' (T_NEW) in C:\xampp\htdocs\developer\wp-content\plugins\liveunited-payments\php_writeexcel\class.writeexcel_workbook.inc.php on line 190

Comment: If you turn warnings on in PHP5.6, you will likely get deprecation messages about this

Comment: You should definitely read [Migrating from PHP 5.6.x to PHP 7.0.x](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.php)

Comment: When i am removing "&" this works fine :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

php7 is not fully compatible with php5, in most cases you have to refactor some code.

First, try to remove "&" near "new"

```
$worksheet =new writeexcel_worksheet($name, $index, $this->_activesheet,
                                  $this->_firstsheet,
                                  $this->_url_format, $this->_parser,
                                  $this->_tempdir);
```

I noticed that error causes in some external library. The best way is update that vendor to version with php7 support